# ¿por qué sale los marcos blancos en las lineas de codigo de sublime txt?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

En la imagen se ve los bordes blancos a veces no me deja leer el código ¿alguien sabe como quitarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo con sublime txt y no se si presione algunos comandos para modificar algo, agredeceria su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se explica en esta pregunta [Sublime Text 3 white boxes around lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469055/sublime-text-3-white-boxes-around-lines), es probable que hayas instalado el package de Sublime Text llamado "Anaconda".

De ser así lo que hay que hacer para deshabilitarlo, tal y como se explica en la respuesta aceptada a esa pregunta, es ir a "Preferences → Package Settings → Anaconda → Settings-User" y allí pegar el siguiente código:

```
{
  "anaconda_linting": false,
}
```

Luego de hacer eso los marcos blancos deberían desaparecer.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS BROOO,  andaba batallando! muchas gracias :)